# Delete the last item in a list using conc operation in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, concatenation

How to write a prolog program to delete the last item in a list using conc operation.

```
cut_last( L1, L2)
```

Following is my answer and can somebody please correct me if I am wrong or is this correct?

```
cut_last(L1,L2):- conc(L2,[_],L1)
```

Comment: I think in Prolog that predicate it's called `append/3`.

Comment: append is the contradictory operation of cut last I guess..!! Append is adding to the end and cut last means remove from the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append/3` to achieve that.

```
cut_last(L1, L2):-
    append(L2, [_], L1).
```

The clause states that `L2` is `L1` without its last element if appending any list of length one to `L2` you will get something that unifies with `L1`.

```
?- cut_last([1,2,3],L).
L = [1, 2] ;
false.
```

Comment: Because the predicate is **not deterministic**. Prolog creates a choice point while satisfying the goal. After reaching the first [and only] solution, it backtracks to that choice point. `false` means there are no further solutions.

Comment: You cannot avoid that with the built-in `append/3` predicate.

Comment: And now I edited my answer in the question which is written using conc operation. Is that not correct? Why id u use a append operation instead of conc operation? Anyway my question is to how to write the program using conc operation.

Comment: What is the conc operation?

Comment: conc refers to Concatenation. I think it is similar to append

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66903/discussion-between-samitha-chathuranga-and-tudor-berariu).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66904/discussion-between-samitha-chathuranga-and-tudor-berariu).